# Apply schema to pyspark dataframe after reading csv

Tags: pyspark

I am currently working on a data pipeline which performs a simple task of read, transform and write. While reading a csv file I am applying a the schema for e.g.

```
      StructField("Call Number",IntegerType(),True),
      StructField("Incident Number",IntegerType(),True),
      StructField("Entry DtTm",DateType() ,True)])
```

which is perfectly fine.
Transformations involve removing some ids which in this case is removing the 2nd column and eventually write to parquet.
Is there any way where I can apply a schema

```
     StructField("Call Number",IntegerType(),True),
     StructField("Entry DtTm",DateType() ,True)])
```

after the transformation step and then write to the parquet table?

Comment: schema should be already updated after you drop a column.  Try checking `df.printSchema()` after the transformation and you should not see the column you dropped.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to `read` the csv data using the `schema` then `drop` the column.

```
df = spark.read.option("schema",schema).csv("")
df.drop('Incident Number').write.parquet
```